# set private and public EC key with OpenSSL from files

Tags: c, file, openssl, key, set

I am making a program which generates a key pair priva and puba for the sender and privb and pubb for the receiver, then I export each one to a file, here is part of my code for the sender:

```
BIGNUM *ppub_a,*ppriv_a;    
point = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(a);
ppub_a = EC_POINT_point2bn(group, point, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED, ppub_a, ctx);
int kk, kk2;
ppriv_a = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(a);
kk = BN_print_fp(keypuba,ppub_a);
kk2 = BN_print_fp(keypriva, ppriv_a);
```

I need this pair priva and puba and the public b(the hex file pubb) key to generate an ECDH key and afterwards an AES key. Then cipher a file.

I dont know how to get and convert this hex file into a public key in order to generate the ECDH key.Could anyone help me? Thx

Answer (score 0):

As nowhere in your code sample do you generate a key or specify group, I can't be sure where the problem lies:

"I dont know how to get and convert this hex file..."   Are you have a problem generating the file (e.g. keypuba is empty or does not contain a key), problems reading the file, or do you just not know how to proceed from here?

FYI, openssl has [hex to Big Number](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html) conversion functions, however you probably do not want to manually compute your own Ephemeral Diffie Hellman parameters, as OpenSSL has an [`ecies_encrypt()`](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-dev&m=128108226522890&q=p5) routine that takes care of that as well as `ecies_key_public_get_hex(EC_KEY *key)` that already takes hex input.

Unfortunately the openssl library was not written as a general crypto API, but as a module to implement SSL. The #1 problem when developers to try use openSSL calls is knowing what interface that they should use and what is an internal interface that they should not use.

Unless you are an expert and have a compelling reason to roll your own version of ECIES, you should use the builtin calls.